# Laravel stored image is tmp not jpg when update data

Tags: laravel

When I update image the data stored is tmp, not an image file.

Here's my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $change = Post::findorfail($id);
    $before = $change->image;
    
    $post = [
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'tags_id' => $request['tags_id'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
        'image' => $before,
    ];

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $request->image->move(public_path().'/image', $before);
   }

    $change->update($post);

    return redirect('post');
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group row mb-4">
            <label class="col-form-label text-md-right col-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Featured Image</label>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
              <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" value="{{ $data->image }}">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have no idea why you are doing this: $request->image->move(public_path().'/image', $before);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save request `image` file into system instead of moving old image file.

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $change = Post::findorfail($id);

    $image = $request->hasFile('image')
        ? $request->photo->store('image', 'public')
        : $change->image;

    $post = [
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'tags_id' => $request['tags_id'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
        'image' => '/storage/' . $image,
    ];

    $change->update($post);

    return redirect('post');
}
```

This will save new image into `/storage/public/image/` path. To make this address accessible through url, you must create a symlink from public path to storage path by running this:

```sh
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create a `storage` symlink in `/public` folder which points to `/storage/public` path. Read the complete documentation about this functionality here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk